# How to put mp3 music in my web application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Does anyone know how to put mp3 music with auto resume even the user change page in my web application.

I want it to continuously played while the user go to the another page in my web application.

Can anyone help me how to do that?

Comment: Use HTML5 to add music in your website

Comment: You'll need to build your page to run off of a single site and use javascript (and possibly jQuery) to dynamically update the page content, address bar URL, and history.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n882G/ This may help you

Comment: For the song to keep playing while you navigate the site, you either have to use ajax like remus pointed out, or sessionStorage or Cookies and on the window.onbeforeunload event, store the song data (position,index,etc), but i highly recommend the ajax approach, since in the second one you will have a subtle pause or a big one depending on the users conection

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML5 for add music to ur website.

You can capture the minute and second when you change of page and save it in a cookie, but the song will stop and start from where you indicate. The best way is to do it with ajax.